# Django Allauth - Add context to password reset e-mail

Tags: django, django-allauth

For this project I'm using Django Allauth to get users to signup and authenticate.

To add the users "first_name" to the context of the confirmation e-mail link I've inherited from the DefaultAccountAdapter and added the first_name to the e-mail context.

```
#adapter.py
class CustomEmailAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

def get_email_confirmation_url(self, request, emailconfirmation):
    """Constructs the email confirmation (activation) url.
    Note that if you have architected your system such that email
    confirmations are sent outside of the request context `request`
    can be `None` here.
    """
    url = reverse(
        "account_confirm_email",
        args=[emailconfirmation.key])
    ret = build_absolute_uri(
        request,
        url)
    return ret

def send_confirmation_mail(self, request, emailconfirmation, signup):
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        activate_url = self.get_email_confirmation_url(
            request,
            emailconfirmation)
        ctx = {
            "first_name": emailconfirmation.email_address.user.first_name, # <-- Added first_name to the context
            "user": emailconfirmation.email_address.user,
            "activate_url": activate_url,
            "current_site": current_site,
            "key": emailconfirmation.key,
        }
        if signup:
            email_template = 'account/email/email_confirmation_signup'
        else:
            email_template = 'account/email/email_confirmation'
        self.send_mail(email_template,
                       emailconfirmation.email_address.email, ctx)
```

I now want to do the same for the password reset e-mail but I don't think this is possible to add this to the custom AccountAdpater.

Any ideas how to add some context to the password reset e-mail, I would like to start my e-mail with "Dear John,"

Thanks in advance!